# Theory on learning with probabilistically labeled data

Tags: machine-learning

Is there any theory on using **vaguely/probabilistically labeled** data? For example is it possible to do classification with training data which only has an estimation on the probability for different groups of the training data being true?

Example:

- training data points **a1,a2** : 90% true
- training data points **b2,b2** : 50% true
- training data points **c1,c2** : 30% true

And you want to find out if a new data point **d** is true or false (or perhaps with what probability)? based on some similarity measure with the training data **a-c**.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like classical Bayes problem, no?

Like probability that given fish is 90% Sea-bass and 50% Salmon, without any additional information?

This will result in any learning algorithm to classify class A to minimize error on any sample.

Comment: I think I was a little bit unclear in my question(done an edit); but it's actually the training data that has probabilistic labels for example we have that 90% of the sea-basses is health and 50% of the Salmons, how probable is it for this fish (holding it in my hand) to be healthy by some algorithm which only can see how close they are to bass or salmon respectively. You are perhaps still right?, but I felt that I needed to clarify my intent.

Comment: After your clarification, the problem is easier to solve; you've just said it. You have distances between points. I can suggest a clustering algorithm, to find a clusters - in your example cluster a,b and c; when you get a point "d" - count distances to centers of the clusters and find nearest two; then take those distances, and cluster probabilities (f.e. da = 1, db = 2, a = 90, b= 50) and then solve x=(a-b)/(da+db); P = a-x.  P is the probability (90-50/3 in this example):) I hope I was clear too

Answer (score 0):

Partial membership in for example clustering (GMM or example), where each datapoint has a dirichlet distribution on the probability of laying in each class.

Or perhaps something in "Learning with Label Noise" can give you an answer, most learners are theoretically expecting cleanly labelled data, but there is some theory behind working with noisy labels:
[Learning_with_Label_Noise](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/neurocomputing/call-for-papers/special-issue-on-advances-in-learning-with-label-noise/)

## Edit

Uncertain evidence or soft-evidence.

for a model p(x, y) we have y' is soft-evidence about y and which to compute p(x|y') then

p(x|y') = sum_y p(x, y|y') = sum_y p(x|y, y')p(y|y') = sum_y p(x|y)p(y|y')

where hard-evidence is a special case where p(y|y') = dirac(y-y')